# $2^{n+1}|2^{2^n}$ and $2^{2^n}+1|2^{2^{n+1}}-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

$2^{n+1}|2^{2^n}$ and $2^{2^n}+1|2^{2^{n+1}}-1$

I have not been able to show the above. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Done any work on it?

Comment: $2^{n+1}|2^{2^n}$ is easy, $2^{2^n}$ has more $2's$ than $2^{n+1}$

Comment: Just show that $n+1\leq2^n\leq2^{n+1}$.

Answer (score 5):

Since $2^n\ge n+1,\;\forall n\in\Bbb N$ then we have

$$\frac{2^{2^n}}{2^{n+1}}=2^{2^n-n-1}\in\Bbb N$$

For the second notice that

$$2^{2^{n+1}}-1=\left(2^{2^n}\right)^2-1=(2^{2^n}-1)(2^{2^n}+1)$$

Comment: This is such an awesome answer. Short and sweet. Bravo!

Comment: @induktio Thanks for your appreciation:)

Comment: When I saw the question, I immediately thought of induction (if you look at some of my past answers concerning induction problems, I try to be clear and go in depth; as a result, my answers are often rather long but at least clear)--I almost dropped my pen when I saw this beautiful answer. **Short. Clear.** -- *excellent travail*! The *only* thing I could think of that would make me even happier would be if your answer were completely translated into symbolism with logic--no words at all! Sorry...don't know why I'm so giddy haha. Nicest answer I've seen in a while. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** First one : induction, Second one: $a^2-b^2= (a-b)(a+b)$